# Talend Studio does not show dropdown menu of branches in Select Existing Project stage

Tags: talend

When trying to open an existing project after selecting any other project besides the first one that is selected by default, all branches for all projects are not showing anymore even though branches do exist. The refresh button does not have any effect.

Talend Studio version: 7.2.1
OS used: Windows 11
java version "11.0.18" 2023-01-17 LTS. Also tried with openjdk version "1.8.0_372"

[image: Branch menu not working]

Comment: it seems that there is a problem accessing GIT repository. You got the list of projects right, so your user is correctly connecting to TAC. But to get list of branches, you should access Git repository.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is not with git. When I start Talend and open the project selection window, I can see branches for the first project (the one, selected by default) and the problem arises only when I try to switch to any other project. Also, I can access all repos and branches using webUI/terminal with the same credentials.

Comment: Please make sure this issue has been reported to [Talend's technical support](https://www.talend.com/technical-support/).